# Reshape vs. tidyr for repeated measures with multiple dependent variables (2)

Tags: r, reshape2, melt, tidyr

I have the following sample data of 5 cases with three repeated measures for two dependent variables "Rapport" and "STRS":

```
df1<-structure(list(SubID = structure(1:5, .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
"38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", 
"49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", 
"60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", 
"71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", 
"82", "83", "84"), class = "factor"), Gender = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("#NULL!", "1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
Age = structure(c(5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("#NULL!", 
"10", "11", "8", "9"), class = "factor"), Rapport.1 = structure(c(22L, 
25L, 19L, 10L, 18L), .Label = c("#NULL!", "1.1", "1.85", 
"2.45", "2.5", "2.55", "2.6", "2.75", "2.8", "2.85", "2.9", 
"2.95", "3.2", "3.25", "3.3", "3.35", "3.4", "3.45", "3.5", 
"3.55", "3.6", "3.65", "3.7", "3.75", "3.8", "3.85", "3.9", 
"3.95"), class = "factor"), Rapport.2 = structure(c(29L, 
31L, 27L, 17L, 9L), .Label = c("#NULL!", "1.25", "1.4", "1.6", 
"1.95", "2.05", "2.3", "2.35", "2.45", "2.5", "2.65", "2.7", 
"2.75", "2.8", "2.85", "3", "3.05", "3.1", "3.15", "3.2", 
"3.35", "3.4", "3.45", "3.5", "3.55", "3.6", "3.65", "3.7", 
"3.75", "3.8", "3.85", "3.9", "3.95", "4"), class = "factor"), 
Rapport.3 = structure(c(32L, 35L, 22L, 22L, 5L), .Label = c("#NULL!", 
"1.35", "1.45", "1.6", "1.75", "1.85", "1.9", "1.95", "2.05", 
"2.1", "2.25", "2.3", "2.35", "2.4", "2.45", "2.6", "2.75", 
"2.8", "2.9", "2.95", "3", "3.05", "3.1", "3.2", "3.25", 
"3.3", "3.35", "3.4", "3.45", "3.5", "3.55", "3.6", "3.7", 
"3.75", "3.8", "3.85"), class = "factor"), STRS.1 = structure(c(33L, 
10L, 8L, 18L, 29L), .Label = c("#NULL!", "100", "102", "103", 
"104", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", "112", "113", 
"114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", "122", "123", 
"124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", "132", "133", "69", 
"71", "73", "85", "88", "89", "92", "97", "99"), class = "factor"), 
STRS.2 = structure(c(37L, 19L, 9L, 22L, 21L), .Label = c("#NULL!", 
"100", "101", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "110", 
"111", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", 
"121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", 
"131", "132", "136", "137", "138", "139", "158", "63", "76", 
"80", "91", "94", "95", "98", "99"), class = "factor"), STRS.3 = structure(c(31L, 
11L, 19L, 23L, 22L), .Label = c("#NULL!", "102", "104", "105", 
"106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", "112", "114", "117", 
"118", "119", "120", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", 
"128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "66", 
"70", "75", "81", "85", "87", "88", "94", "98"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("SubID", 
"Gender", "Age", "Rapport.1", "Rapport.2", "Rapport.3", "STRS.1", 
"STRS.2", "STRS.3"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

To convert the dataset from wide to long form I ran the following code:

```
df2<-reshape(df1, varying = 4:9, sep = ".", direction = 'long')
View(df2)
```

The result is what I wanted but I don’t want the additional “id” column added in column 8 since it’s just a duplicate of my “SubID” in column 2. I’d also like to know if I need to make sure that I have a separator in my repeater measure variable headings in order for this function to work (e.g., “Rapport.1, Rapport.2, etc.”).

I also want to know how to produce my desired results with the “melt” function in the reshape pkg. and the “gather” function in the tidyr pkg. 
When I try “melt” below, I get an error and it won’t run:

```
df3<-melt(df1, id.vars=c("SubID","Gender","Age"),
measure.vars=c("Rapport.1","Rapport.2","Rapport.3","STRS.1","STRS.2","STRS.3,
variable.name=c("Rapport","STRS"),
value.name=("Rapport","STRS"))
```

When I try “gather” below, I get one column that contains the variable names “Rapport.1…” and “STRS.1…” stacked and another column with the values:

```
df4<-gather(df1, Rapport, STRS, Rapport.1:STRS.3)
View(df4)
```

I know there are benefits to using both of these packages so I’d like to understand how to produce my desired results with the “gather” and “melt” functions. Can anybody assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the `tidyr` version. You need to first `gather` the columns, then `separate` out the time columns and finally `spread` the data.

```
require(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  gather(key, value, -c(SubID, Gender, Age)) %>% 
  separate(key, c("key", "time")) %>%
  spread(key, value, convert = TRUE)
##    SubID Gender Age time Rapport STRS
## 1      1      2   9    1    3.65   73
## 2      1      2   9    2    3.75   76
## 3      1      2   9    3    3.60   66
## 4      2      1  11    1    3.80  110
## 5      2      1  11    2    3.85  120
## 6      2      1  11    3    3.80  112
## 7      3      2  10    1    3.50  108
## 8      3      2  10    2    3.65  108
## 9      3      2  10    3    3.05  124
## 10     4      1  10    1    2.85  118
## 11     4      1  10    2    3.05  123
## 12     4      1  10    3    3.05  128
## 13     5      2  11    1    3.45  132
## 14     5      2  11    2    2.45  122
## 15     5      2  11    3    1.75  127
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution using the [devel `data.table` version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table) # v >= 1.9.5
melt(setDT(df1), measure = list(4:6, 7:9))
#     SubID Gender Age variable value1 value2
#  1:     1      2   9        1   3.65     73
#  2:     2      1  11        1    3.8    110
#  3:     3      2  10        1    3.5    108
#  4:     4      1  10        1   2.85    118
#  5:     5      2  11        1   3.45    132
#  6:     1      2   9        2   3.75     76
#  7:     2      1  11        2   3.85    120
#  8:     3      2  10        2   3.65    108
#  9:     4      1  10        2   3.05    123
# 10:     5      2  11        2   2.45    122
# 11:     1      2   9        3    3.6     66
# 12:     2      1  11        3    3.8    112
# 13:     3      2  10        3   3.05    124
# 14:     4      1  10        3   3.05    128
# 15:     5      2  11        3   1.75    127
```